# Azure App service Single Sign On

Tags: c#, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, access-token

I'm developing a mobile app service using C# and hosting it in Azure. I have used authorization for the client and it's working fine. Now I want to internally call another web service hosted in Azure under the same tenant.

I'm getting the token from `X-ZUMO-AUTH` from the client call of the service I have developed.  My problem is that I'm not sure how to pass this Azure authorization token to the other web service I'm calling internally on C# code.

Could anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: If it's a Bearer token just send an `Authorization: Bearer ey....` header with your request.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the *on-behalf-of* flow. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) explains the scenario (look for *On-Behalf-Of*) - and [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) show you how to do this on an ASP.NET application.